# what is Postman's port?

Tags: node.js, express, postman

in my index.js file I have

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
var cors = require("cors");

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["localhost:2200", "localhost:2201"],
  })
);
```

In addition to the origins defined above, I need to add the origin for postman for testing and development.

Comment: Postman does not have an origin (it's not a browser and isn't running in a webpage that would determine the origin) and does not implement CORs so you don't have to worry about it for requests coming from Postman.  CORs is something only implemented in a browser and restricts access to some requests from within a webpage.  It's the browser that implements that restriction.  When testing from Postman, there will be no CORs restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postman does not have an origin (it's not a browser and isn't running in a webpage that would determine the origin) and does not implement CORS so you don't have to worry about it for requests coming from Postman.

CORS is something only implemented in a browser and restricts access to some requests from within a webpage.  It's the browser that implements that restriction.  When testing from Postman, there will be no CORS restrictions.

> what is Postman's port?

Since it has no origin and doesn't implement CORS, there is no associated port.